# Do build tools for Vimscript exist?

Tags: vim

I'd like to build a small set of vimscript libraries, however, it seems that the only way to use them would be to load them all globally into vim.

Furthermore, it means that if i wanted to share a single script that depends on those, i'd have to share to them all, which sounds tiresome.

What i was hoping for is some common.js and webpack style approach to vimscript,
does such a thing exist. Something that:

- Resolves dependencies
- Allows for vimscript files to be "bundled" together into one file.

Everything that i found, winds up being a plugin manager, rather than a plugin build tool.

Do such things exist?

Comment: I am not aware of such a thing.

Answer (score 7):

### The situation so far, up to Vim 8.

There is no script isolation. When a script is loaded, it's globally. The script can hide variables and functions, but that's all.

Sharing/exporting a function is quite easy: we drop it in an autoload plugin, and we just have to use that function named `dirrelatativeto_rtp#subdir#suddir...#scriptname#funcname()`. If the script `scriptname.vim` is installed in `dirrelatativeto_rtp/subdir/subdir` somewhere in a directory registered in `'runtimepath'`, it'll get loaded automatically.

Regarding commands, abbreviations, mappings... they are meant to be defined in plugin files, or ftplugin files -- other approaches are possible when we want  submodes. Also we cannot use them naively from an autoload plugin or when a script is being loaded -- we'll have to explicitly use `:runtime` to load the script where this command/mapping/... is defined (as we'd do an `import`  in Python).

Yet, like with Python, scripts aren't installed automagically on our  system. It's still up to us to trigger manually the installation of scripts.

We can decide to have library plugins and other plugins that depend on these libraries. But, we need either to tell the end-user everything that must be installed manually, or kindly tell him/her to stop using a plugin manager that don't understand dependencies.

This has been a personal rant of mine for years, the trendy plugin managers don't understand dependencies. There are so far only two plugin managers that do so:

- Vim-Addon-Manager (aka VAM): it relies on a central repository (vim-pi) to install a plugin (and its dependencies) with just its name (e.g. `:InstallAddon fugitive`, `:InstallAddon lh-cpp`). Unfortunately the central repository is no longer maintained and we can't register new names. Fortunately, we can always install anything with `:InstallAddon github:{N}/{repo}`. Other functions are available for installing from the .vimrc.
- and vim-flavor which is written in ruby, and which install plugins as Vim 8 packages.

Both have their own syntax to declare dependencies. Unlike VAM, we can specify constraints on plugin versions with vim-flavor.

Last thing, if we don't want to distribute all files, we can organize them as several "plugins". But beware of cyclic dependencies. And be kind to end users that are using these trendy plugins managers that don't understand dependencies as they'll need to explicitly install many "plugins"

### Starting from Vim 9

We can start to isolate imported plugins in the sense that two plugins can define a function or a command with a same name. Again, this feature seems to mimic Python way of doing things.

However, I expect global stuff like autocommands to continue to operate globally. For instance: I don't see how we could have two template expander plugins running concurrently.

Vim 9 new scripting language won't change anything to the installation of plugins we depend on.

Disclaimer: It has been almost 2 decades now that I've been maintaining my plugins as a bunch of interdependent plugins, organized around a few library plugins, as I don't like to duplicate a same thing several times. In my rant about [dependencies & co](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/design_notes.md#regarding-dependencies), I explore quickly other alternative approaches available to us.

### Back to the bundling/packaging question (EDIT)

We have ways to package files together.

- We can always manually define plugins: put files together in a directory tree, play with git and so on.
- We can define tarballs.
- We can also define vimballs. Vimballs are a quite old solution for installable archives: files are put in their right directory and documentation tags are produced. There are ways to produce vimballs. I continue to maintain [script**s** that help producing them](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/mkVba/mk-lh-vim-lib.vim) for all my plugins. But in all honesty, this is not what people expect to have nowadays to install plugins. I just keep them around in case I release new versions of my plugins on vim.org.

In any case, neither of these solutions end up defining one single file we put somewhere in our `~/.vim/` directory. And I think we will never have something like that because:

- Isolation is not perfect. Even with Vim 9 new scripting language: I don't see how we could correctly handle duplication of autocommands. If a same file, that defines autocommands, is duplicated in different versions in several distributed "plugins" I don't see how Vim could handle that correctly.
- Vim expects different files in different places: ftplugins, plugins (the original meaning in vim context, not the  set of files that could be installed together), syntax files, fold plugins, indent plugins, colorschemes, langmaps, and so on. Vim architecture does not expect everything in a single file.

For these reasons, I cannot see how we could have build systems that build single files ready to be distributed. It could work in some cases (pure collections of functions and "classes"), but not in the general case.